# Where can I find the English translation of some well-known-papers in different braches of mathematics.

Tags: reference-request, translation-request

All I want to find are some really classic papers like papers mentioned in [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_important_publications_in_mathematics#Topology) to provide me with some motivation and original intention from the founder of the theory rather than some not-so-well-known papers aiming to do historical review.

So far, all I can found is nothing more than some paper collections of few famous mathematians like Euler, Riemann, Poincaré.

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Could you clarify which topic and which period are you interested in?

Comment: Among the examples of mathematicians you cited, Euler (mostly in Latin), once translated, is usually very clear. Riemann and especially Poincaré aren't easy to read (with exceptions : the philosophical essays of Poincaré are a delight).